# How use some blocking methods while using Quarkus Hibernate Reactive with quarkus-reactive-client?

Tags: java, hibernate, vert.x, quarkus

I am trying to call a reactive rest but while doing it I have to call another request inside it and create few folders but quarkus-hibernate-reactive is showing below error what is best practice to it?

```
Error:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The current thread cannot be blocked: vert.x-eventloop-thread-2
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.UniBlockingAwait.await(UniBlockingAwait.java:29)
```

My code is as below:

```
@POST
@javax.ws.rs.Path("/add") 
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
public Uni<Response> addUser(@HeaderParam("userName") String addedBy) throws Exception{
     //Here I have one if condition which is checking from database if user exist!

     if (checkUser(addedBy).await().indefinitely().intValue() > 0) {
        //then creatingfolders

        if (createFolders(addedBy) > 0) {
             UserBean u = new UserBean(addedBy);
             return Uni.createFrom().item(userRepository.addUser(u)).onItem().transform(f -> f != null ? Response.ok(f) : Response.ok(null))
                 .onItem().transform(ResponseBuilder::build);
        }
     }
}

public Uni<Long> addUser(UserBean userIN) {
   return Panache.withTransaction(userIN::persist)
                .replaceWith(userIN.getId());
}
```

How we can make it wait for completion of creating folders and checking user exists? I have tried using @Blocking but it didn't worked. Please help

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the same problem (without the reactive part) 

Comment: Adding the `io.smallrye.common.annotation.Blocking` annotation @Blocking on the addUser POST endpoint should have worked as it tells Quarkus to use a worker thread (executor thread) instead of the event loop IO thread.
Are you sure you placed the right annotation?

Answer (score 3):

You should either switch to regular Hibernate ORM instead of Hibernate Reactive, or chain the operations together in a reactive manner.

Instead of doing
`checkUser(addedBy).await().indefinitely().intValue()` do something like:

```
checkUser(addedBy).onItem().transformToUni(count -> {
   ....
})
```

Comment: from transformToUni how can we return Uni<Response> as "addUser" method return type is Uni<Response>

Comment: `transformToUni` takes a function that returns a `Uni`. See https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/getting-started/transforming-items-async for more examples

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question is `runSubscriptionOn` (or `emitOn`) - the vertx event loop thread does not allow you to run blocking code in order to not block event processing. But this happens only when you use `await()` or similar compositions where vertx can actually tell that it is being blocked, not when other blocking or expensive operations are run (like blocking IO operations, mutexes, etc.), in *either* case you should run on a different worker/pool:

```java
import io.smallrye.mutiny.infrastructure.Infrastructure;

Uni<String> uni = Uni.createFrom()
        .item(this::invokeRemoteServiceUsingBlockingIO)
        .runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool());
//                                        ''''''''''''''''''''
```

Note that you will obviously need to use a lazy item (supplier, etc.) or you'll still block the event thread.

Also see: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/latest/guides/imperative-to-reactive/#running-blocking-code-on-subscription

Also, vertx has a filesystem module (you can inject Vertx in your Bean), which lets you reactively deal with files, so in this case you don't even need that:

```java
@Inject
io.vertx.mutiny.core.Vertx vertx;
//       ''''''
Uni<Void> uni = vertx.fileSystem().mkdir("/foo");
```

**Note**: Since writing this I tend to prefer `emitOn` over `runSubscriptionOn`, they achieve the same result, but while `runSubscriptionOn` affects the chain before the method, emitOn affects the chain *after* the method, this has proven to be easier to work with - but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you already tried the Blocking annotation, but did you use the right one? I believe there are two of them and only one work.

Comment: I have used this one io.smallrye.common.annotation.Blocking